# how to upload photo to picasa web album using Data Api?

Tags: android, picasa

I want to upload a photo to picasa web album through from android using data api. i see this link https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java  but this does not help me at all. can any one give an example code to upload a photo to picasa web album or other tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official code sample for uploading a Image,

```
URL albumPostUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/username/albumid/albumid");

PhotoEntry myPhoto = new PhotoEntry();
myPhoto.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Puppies FTW"));
myPhoto.setDescription(new PlainTextConstruct("Puppies are the greatest."));
myPhoto.setClient("myClientName");

MediaFileSource myMedia = new MediaFileSource(new File("/home/liz/puppies.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
myPhoto.setMediaSource(myMedia);

PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = myService.insert(albumPostUrl, myPhoto);
```

A complete example code is available here,

[Connect to Picasa album from Android using OAuth2](http://rcs34-android.blogspot.com/2012/09/connect-to-picasa-album-from-android.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've gotten to that stage. I'm still trying to get a camera Bitmap to be uploaded directly to Picasa.